# Using Isolated Coax Cable as Ethernet Connection?

Tags: ethernet, cable

Sounds possible, but haven't found anything that's affordable or that looks legit that can achieve this in ($10-$50 range)

Basically, I have an isolated coax cable that goes from my office to the cable coax splitter in the master room closest where also my wifi router/switch is camping in. I'm not using the cable for anything, and I much rather NOT use wifi or those ethernet via power line adapters. (I'm a bit of a stickler with security, I know...)

But if there truly isn't something as such or two expensive, I may as well find a router in bridge mode support, and crank up the security to max.

P.S encase you are wondering, most parts of the house has wired Ethernet, except for the office room, and I use the wifi for guests or my phone.

Comment: Ironically, original 1980s Ethernet (after ALOHA and before techn for high speed over twisted pair existed) used RG-8 'thicknet' and then RG-58A 'thinnet'; see Wikipedia under 10BASE5 and 10BASE2. But if your coax was (or is) for cableTV that is usually RG-59, which has a different impedance that I believe will defeat the old transceivers even if you can find a working one. OTOH google 'ethernet over coax' gives me numerous modern devices designed to use video coax, though not as cheap as you want.

Answer (score 2):

Though [there are Ethernet-coax-Ethernet adapters](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FKTMWDE), they're ~US$70-100, and some offer limited bandwidth. You might find it more economical to snake a Cat-5e or Cat-6 cable along the path of the existing coax.

To use the existing coax as a snake, first check that it is not stapled down by pulling at one end and seeing if the other end moves appreciably.

- If the cable seems free, remove the type-F connector on the coax and **tightly** tie and tape the Ethernet cable to the end of the coax, making the transition as smooth, as flexible and as thin as possible so it does not get caught inside the wall.
- Slowly pull the far end of the coax, snaking the the Ethernet behind the coax.
- If the coax gets caught, perhaps due to connectors or splitters inside the wall, then use the Ethernet cable to pull the coax back out. In that case, you'll need to put the F connector back on the coax and go with one of the alternatives.